# How to use apps script or add-ons in Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am trying to create some Apps Script (or add-ons) in a Google Form but the documentation does not match the application.  For example, [this](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en) says to enable add-ons in the menu but that options does not exist. Other documentation mentions the script editor, but that seems to be missing also.  Is there some other way to enable this?

Edit: In the "three dots" menu in a Form I see preview, settings, undo, star, make a copy, move to folder, move to trash, get pre-filled link, print, add collaborators, help center, report a problem, and preferences.

Comment: Google Forms are a Web Application.  Your question might be better for the [Stack Exchange Community](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-forms) or the [Google Docs Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/LZpAOE4VFSI)  Add-ons to not need to be enabled unless you are in an organization using a paid Google account, like GSuite.  In that case the domain administrator can prevent users from installing Add-ons.  In that case you would need to contact the domain administrator to change a setting for the organization.

Comment: The Stack Exchange community you mentioned has this:

Don't use this tag for questions about forms that use the Google Apps   Script HTML Service. Instead use only the tag google-apps-script.

Also, [this] (https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/426zGMwgmuw;context-place=topicsearchin/docs/enable$20script$20editor$20in$20forms) says that Apps Script is rapid release only for Forms.  Is this still the case?

Comment: An input form can be custom programmed with HTML.  That is very different than a Google Form.  A Google Form is a pre-made application.  A Google Form has nothing to do with HTML Service.  An Add-on uses HTML Service, but the HTML service is something that the developer of the Add-on would use, not the user of the Add-on.  I don't know anything about the rapid release program or it's current status.

Comment: The "three dots" menu that you describe it's shown when the window is "too narrow". In my case the "Add-ons..." option is shown but not the "Script editor..." option.  What browser and operative system are you using? Are you using a consumer account or a G Suite account?

Comment: Wow, that was it!  I maximized my window and I can now see the Script Editor link.  I cannot believe that Google hides this when Chrome is not big enough, that is just terrible design.  If you post this as the answer I will accept it.  Thank you, Rubén.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very likely that you are using a G Suite account from an organization that has not enabled the use of add-ons. Ask your G Suite administrator about this.

Reference

- [Enable add-ons in Docs editors](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4530135?hl=en)

Comment: In regular Docs (as opposed to Forms) I see both the script editor and the Add-Ons menu.  Are you saying the at app script/add-ons for Forms has to be enabled separately from Docs?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that. Please update your question to describe where do you look at the Google Forms editor. Hint: Look at the More (three dots) button

Comment: I updated it.  See nothing related to the script editor or add-ons.

Comment: I just retried this and now I see the option.  I guess the Admin finally enabled it.  Thanks, Rubén.